Why isn't the 'labelColor' callback for the Chart.js Tooltip applying any changes?
I'm using vue-chartjs to display a line chart, and right now I'm customizing the appearance. I'm finding that certain attributes to style the Tooltip are not working. I'm currently trying the following approach to select a background color based on the value of the data. I've copied the code straight from the Chart.js documentation and put in my ternary operator to select a background color.
const options = {
        elements: {
          line: {
            borderColor: '#15c63c',
            borderCapStyle: 'round',
          },
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            grid: {
              display: false,
              color: 'rgba(150,150,150,.3)',
            },
          },
          x: {
            grid: {
              color: 'rgba(150,150,150,0.1)',
            },
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'April 2024',
          },
          tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,225,225,0.75)',
            displayColors: false,
            padding: 12,
            titleAlign: 'center',
            caretPadding: 4,
            callbacks: {
              label: function (context) {
                let label = context.dataset.label || ''

                if (context.parsed.y !== null && context.parsed.y >= 0) {
                  const suffix = context.parsed.y === 1 ? '' : 's'
                  label += '+' + context.parsed.y + ' unit' + suffix
                }

                return label
              },
              labelColor: function(context) {
                let backgroundColor = context.parsed.y >= 0 ? 'rgba(21,198,60,0.7)' : 'rgba(204,0,0,0.7)'
                return {
                  borderColor: 'rgb(255,253,250)',
                  backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderDash: [2, 2],
                  borderRadius: 8,
                }
              },
              labelTextColor: function () {
                return 'rgb(255,253,250)'
              },
            },
          },
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      }

If I remove the options.plugins.tooltip.backgroundColor, then the tooltip uses the default values. The 'labelTextColor' callback works as intended. I've also noticed that no matter what I do, I can't change the borderColor of the tooltip. I've tried options.plugins.tooltip.borderColor = 'rgb(255,253,250)' but that doesn't work either.
I've also done console.log(context.parsed.y) within the labelColor callback and confirmed that the rgb values are showing up in the console.
I've tried looking on SO, as well as the GH but everything I've found seems to be from 4 or 6 years ago and is no longer relevant.

Maybe a different version of the package? What about the component in your Vue devtools? Do you see some props on it as intended? Do you see the color one?

Also, do you maybe have a [repro] that we could play around with so that I do not need to setup an entire project just for the troubleshooting?

The labelColor callback is used to style the symbol to the left of the label text, also called "color box"; it has no effect with your configuration because of the displayColors: false option which completely removes the color box.

To set the border color for the whole tooltip you have to use the borderColor at the top level of tooltip configuration, where backgroundColor is; both are scriptable. Note that by default the borderWidth is zero, so to see some border you have to set the width too. The scriptable arguments of borderColor are rather thin, so you'd probably be better off by using an event handler callback like afterBody to adapt the border color to the content of the tooltip, see fiddle example.

@kissu -- thank you for the response. I've been super busy with work and will try to give you a MRE tomorrow.

@kikon -- I appreciate your response. I've been very busy and will attempt them tomorrow.

@kikon provided the roadmap for the answer. The labelColor callback was trying to style an element I was wanting hidden. I moved all border settings up to the top level of the tooltip object. Then using @kikon's fiddle example I did an afterBody callback to dynamically set the backgroundColor of the tooltip.
tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,225,225,0.75)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255,253,250)',
            displayColors: false,
            padding: 12,
            titleAlign: 'center',
            caretPadding: 4,
            callbacks: {
              label: context => {
                let label = context.dataset.label || ''

                if (context.parsed.y !== null && context.parsed.y >= 0) {
                  label += '+' + context.parsed.y
                }

                const suffix = context.parsed.y === 1 ? '' : 's'
                label += ' unit' + suffix

                return label
              },
              labelTextColor: () => {
                return 'rgb(255,253,250)'
              },
              afterBody: context => {
                const backgroundColor = context[0].parsed.y >= 0 ? 'rgba(21,198,60,0.7)' : 'rgba(204,0,0,0.7)'
                context[0].chart.tooltip.options.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
              },
            },
          }

